# How to launch a Winforms app from a windows-service

Tags: winforms, process, windows-services, interactive, topshelf

Hello i am trying to launch an interactive process - a `winforms` app - from a windows service on the current session.
I do not know how to do that.I am using `TopShelf` and i tried launching the process using the `WhenSessionChanged` hook provided by `TopShelf`.
I can get the `sessionId`

```
 var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x => {
                    x.Service<MyService>(s => {
                        s.ConstructUsing((h) => new MyService());
                        s.WhenStarted(t => t.Run());
                        s.WhenStopped(t => t.Stop());
                        s.WhenSessionChanged((anubis, args) => {
                              string winformsPath="D://WinFormsApp/Wf.exe"
                              int sessionId = args.SessionId;
                              Process process = new Process();
                              process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(winformsPath);
                              process.Start();
                         });
                    });
                    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                    x.SetServiceName(Constants.ISO.NAME);
                    x.SetDisplayName(Constants.ISO.DISPLAY);
                    x.SetDescription(Constants.ISO.DESCRIPTION);
                });
```

I do not know what to do with the `sessionId`.
**P.S**
I did not post the definition of `MyService` because it is not important in our case.I just want to launch the winforms on the current session.

Comment: The core magic is to call the Win32 API `CreateProcessAsUser`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw You can find tons via a search engine.

Comment: But in this case i would need to know beforehand the user and password of the current session.

Comment: Please do a thorough search. For users whose sessions are active, you only need to duplicate the token of that active session. But for users without active logon sessions, you do need the credentials.

Comment: This use case is only for users whose sessions are active.Regarding the duplication of tokens , is it also in the documentation you provided?

Comment: I have tried launching the `winform` using the `DuplicateToken` and `CreateProcessAsUser` but i still get this error when i run `form.ShowDialog()` :`Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application`